# How to get Windows loggedin username in IIS defind anonymous + windows authentication

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, windows-authentication, iis-10, applicationpoolidentity

framework : ASP.NET CORE 2.2 as web-api
Server: IIS-10 (Windows server 2016)

I need to work with both **WindowsAuthentication** and **AnonymousAuthentication**.
I have these 2 options to somehow get the **Windows LoggedIn User**:

```
User.Identity.Name; 

System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

I use them in an end-point (controller method) which is reached anonymous.

Everything works fine with IISExpress, but when working with IIS (local or after deploy), I can't get the wanted results:

```
User.Identity.Name; // return null

System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name //return IISAPPPOOL\<Application pool name>
```

Application Pool Identity is ApplicationPoolIdentity.

How can I get the **Windows LoggedIn Username** in this configuration (anonymous + windows authentication)?

Comment: "I need to work with both WindowsAuthentication and AnonymousAuthentication." I think you don't know what you are asking for. Enabling anonymous authentication on IIS automatically prevents all other methods (like Windows authentication) from working. Forget about IIS Express, because it is not IIS, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: If you enable both Windows Authentication and anonymous authentication at the same time, then only anonymous authentication will be enabled, if you want to get Windows Log Username, you need to disable anonymous authentication. and this link should help you: [https://richhewlett.com/2011/02/15/getting-a-users-username-in-asp-net](https://richhewlett.com/2011/02/15/getting-a-users-username-in-asp-net).

Comment: But Microsoft tell is possible use WindowsAuthentication and AnonymoutsAuthentication enabled on the same time: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#allow-anonymous-access-1

Comment: Has Windows Authentication be installed in IIS Server? Having it enabled on the project side is not sufficient.